# Validation for Javascript string based specific validation rules

Tags: javascript

I have an search query that I need to validate based on a set of criteria
example expression :

```
"chicken" AND ("salad" OR "sandwich") NOT "coop"
```

RULES

- Opening and closing parenthesis i.e. (())//valid (()//invalid
- Operators AND|OR|NOT
- Double operator i.e. AND AND || OR OR etc //false
- Opening and closing quotations i.e. ""//valid "//invalid

What I have solved is the bracket count:

```
function validate(){
    let searchPhrase= editor.value;
    let characters = searchPhrase.split('');
    let bracketCount = 0;
    let bracketValid;

    //check bracket count
    characters.forEach((char) => {
        if (char === '(') {
            bracketCount++;
        }else if(char === ')') {
            bracketCount--;
        }
    });

    //check if bracket is open or closed  
    if (bracketCount % 2 != 0) {
      bracketValid = false;
      errorMsg.innerHTML = `Have an missing closing bracket`;
    } else {
      bracketValid = true;
      errorMsg.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

The rules I current have written work when written for the first time (left to right) because I use [current] and [previous] positions in the array but when editing the string [current] and [previous] are no longer referring to the end of the array.

Help with writing any of the above rules would be greatly appreciated!

checking for opening and matching closing bracket
https://jsfiddle.net/non_tech_guy/9u4b5vqh/12/

Comment: This kind of decision systems is treated like trees

Comment: I think you cannot simply rely on the _count_ of parenthesis or quotation marks. Consider, for example, the string `'() () "" "" "" "" AND OR NOT chicken salad sandwich coop'`; if you rely only on count, it would pass the validation but I assume it is not what you would consider a valid string.

Comment: What does a binary NOT operator do with its first operand?

Comment: Actually, the parenthesis count works so far in my testing even on a string like '() () ((()))', unless I am missing something. – secan

Comment: maybe this would be a better example "a AND (b OR c) NOT d" which would probably look something like ["a","b"],["a","c"],["d"].

Comment: I have the feeling `NOT "coop"` should be `AND NOT "coop"`. How are you planning to handle the scenario when the statement stands by itself (just `NOT "coop"`)? Because you currently handle `NOT` as a binary operator, not as a unary operator. You could still use the syntax you propose, but you have to be aware that `NOT` can be both binary and unary based on the context. Unary being what you would expect, and binary meaning "and not".

Comment: I have been considering using AND NOT over NOT, thanks.

Comment: I can show you what I have done so far https://jsfiddle.net/non_tech_guy/3q2gcae0/68/ to handle the query validation against the rules.